# AWS Golang CreateSecret() ResourceExistsException on new unique key name

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

Not sure what is going on, this code worked once yesterday.  Now no matter what value I use, AWS is returning a error that it already exists, but that's impossible.

2020/04/17 19:10:30 error ResourceExistsException: The operation failed because the secret /gog1/RandomSiteName3 already exists.

```
_, err = PutParam("/gog1/RandomSiteName3", "test", true, EventGuid)
if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error writing secret: %v ", err)
        return
}



func PutParam(paramName string, paramValue string, encrypt bool, guid string) (output string, err error) {

    svc := secretsmanager.New(AWSSession)
    input := &secretsmanager.CreateSecretInput{
        // ClientRequestToken: aws.String(guid),
        // Description:        aws.String("My test database secret created with the CLI"),
        Name:         aws.String(paramName),
        SecretString: aws.String(paramValue),
    }

    fmt.Printf("putting secret key: %v", paramName)

    _, err = svc.CreateSecret(input)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return

}
```

Comment: "is returning a error that it already exists, but that's impossible." - obviously not impossible....

Comment: I'm creating new names on the fly and it's throwing the error.  It does not already exist.

Comment: Ok, I think I know the problem.. It's an s3 trigger that is firing in a loop.  This func updates a file in s3, and then this func gets called again. infinite loop.  It was hard to see this because it's a lamdba invocation with seperate logs in cloudwatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to an s3 trigger firing in a loop:

> NOTE: If writing to the bucket that triggers the notification, this
>   could cause an execution loop. For example, if the bucket triggers a
>   Lambda function each time an object is uploaded, and the function
>   uploads an object to the bucket, then the function indirectly triggers
>   itself. To avoid this, use two buckets, or configure the trigger to
>   only apply to a prefix used for incoming objects.